# Renaming Xcode project that uses firebase and cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, rename

I have been trying to rename my project that uses firebase and cocoapods using different procedures, but I keep encountering a lot of errors in the end. I would like to know if there is a way changing only the name of the app without changing the name of the entire project.

The app is written in Xcode 7.3.1 using swift 2.2

Comment: you might be looking for Display name in info.plist file. It will change your app name at home screen